# Single Kotlin+libgdx codebase deployed to Android, desktop and browser?

Tags: android, libgdx, kotlin

Is this possible? I'm thinking that deploying to both Android and desktop shouldn't be too hard (since Java can already do it). I learned that Kotlin can also be transpiled to JavaScript. Does this mean that I can deploy the **same codebase** to all three targets, or will I need different code for the browser? (is it even possible to use libgdx when targeting the browser with Kotlin?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your code base. First, Kotlin2JS is not officially released, it has many issues, so code that compiles for JVM will fail to run in JavaScript. Second, your code base should not depend on Java class library (i.e. `java.lang`, `java.util`, `java.io`, etc), since Kotlin2JS is source-to-source transpiler and it knows nothing about Java and Java libraries. LibGDX is written in Java, so you can't write your libGDX game on Kotlin and transpile it to JavaScript.

For now, to transpile any Kotlin/Java/Scala code base, you can use [TeaVM](http://teavm.org/) (it's not related to Kotlin team or JetBrains). The only problem is current stable release found in Maven (0.4.3) does not handle `swap` instruction properly, so you should download `master` branch of TeaVM (which has the appropriate fix) and build it yourself. Another problem is TeaVM does not know anything about `dynamic` keyword and `@native` annotation supported by Kotlin2JS.

Comment: Is the latter problem a show-stopper? As I understand, TeaVM transpiles byte-code, not the source (that's why it's even able to work with Kotlin, unlike GWT which transpiles the source). I can see Kotlin being mentioned on the TeaVM website.

Comment: It's a showstopper on most usecases. So you likely have to be on a bleeding edge to use TeaVM with Kotlin.